# Adjust RealmResult without querying

Tags: android, realm

I'm using a simple instance of RealmRecyclerViewAdapter to handle displaying MyObjects:

```
public class MyObjectsAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<MyObject, MyObjectsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface Listener {
        void onMyObjectClicked(Long myObjectId);
    }

    private Context context;
    private Listener listener;

    public MyObjectsAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<MyObject> data, Listener listener) {
        super(context, data, true);
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

... // Rest of the code.
```

Although this works for simple queries, I have one filter that is too complex for a realm query, so I'll have to filter myself by looping the results. But since I cannot "remove" an object from RealmResults (as it removes it from the realm), I would need to work with a List, which means I would have to rewrite the adapter.

My question is, is there a way to adjust RealmResult in a way that is not based on a realm query?

Comment: `is there a way to adjust RealmResult in a way that is not based on a realm query?` nope, but maybe there could be a way around it depending on the query?

Comment: Possibly: MyObject stores a timestamp in millis, and I need to query for any record between 9am and 5pm regardless of the day.

Comment: You should add an `hour` field that you set when you set the Date. Then you will be able to query between 9 and 17 regardless of day.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - That should work thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write out what @EpicPandaForce suggests.

Add an extra field (`hour`) to your model class:

```
class MyObject extends RealmObject {
    private Date timestamp;
    private int hour;

    public setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        setHour(timestamp.getHours());
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can now use `hour` in your queries.